# Can the Django admin be configured to save generic content types with the id of the base model of an inherited model?

Tags: django, inheritance, django-admin

I'm using Django 1.3.

I have a base model  (not abstract) called BasicPost. I have a model inheriting from it called PostWithImage. BasicPost has a couple of  generic relations.

In models.py:

```
class BasicPost(models.Model):
   ...
   authors = generic.GenericRelation(OrderedCredit,
   verbose_name=_('authors'), blank=True, null=True)
   ...
   tags = generic.GenericRelation(TaggedItem, verbose_name=_('tags'),
                                  blank=True, null=True)
   ...

class PostWithImage(BasicPost):
   ...
```

In admin.py:

```
class TaggedItemInline(generic.GenericTabularInline):
    ...
    model = TaggedItem
    ...

class OrderedCreditInline(generic.GenericTabularInline):
    ... # same concept as above

class BasicPostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [OrderedCreditInline, TaggedItemInline]

class PostWithImageAdmin(BasicPostAdmin):
    ...
```

When I save an object on the PostWithImage admin screen, it sets the content_type of my generic fields equal to PostWithImage. However if I want to now retrieve all posts (irrespective of whether they're a BasicPost, PostWithImage or any other kind of post) with a particular tag, I run into problems. No simple query will do it, because the tags are pointing to a bunch of different models. I have found a workaround, but it's very ugly (see below).

My question is: **Is there a way I can coerce the admin interface into saving the tags with content_type pointing to the base class, i.e. BasicPost?**

Here's the ugly workaround. It's very difficult for a programmer to decipher
and I suspect it generates very expensive database hits.

```
class BasicPost(models.Model)

   # This code uses model_utils select_subclasses method

   def get_related_posts(self):
      tags = self.tags.all()

      return BasicPost.objects.filter(
        pk__in=
            [t.object_id for t in
                TaggedItem.objects.filter(tag__name__in=[t.tag.name for t in tags])
                    if isinstance(t.content_type.model_class()(), BasicPost)])\
                        .select_subclasses().order_by('-date_published')
```

Answer (score 1):

If its not an abstract, than you might have to do it the dirty way. Django documentation shows that if you use a one to many link, that you could basically query everything. Because thats not the case, the dirty way might be the only way. I haven't used enough Django to tell right off the bat.

I would suggest you look at the django book, http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/

This book has it all. When I was programming a django server a month ago, this became my one stop shop reference.

I hope this helps.